# Deferrable Constraints in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, constraints

Do any versions of SQL Server support deferrable constraints (DC)?

Since about version 8.0, [Oracle has supported deferrable constraints](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/03-nov/o63asktom.html) - constraints that are only evaluated when you commit a statement group, not when you insert or update individual tables. Deferrable constraints differ from just disabling/enabling constraints, in that the constraints are still active - they are just evaluated later (when the batch is committed).

The benefit of DC is that they allow updates that individually would be illegal to be evaluated that cummulatively result in a valid end state. An example is creating circular references in a table between two rows where each row requires a value to exist. No individual insert statement would pass the constraint - but the group can.

To clarify my goal, I am looking to port an ORM implementation in C# to SQLServer - unfortunately the implementation relies on Oracle DC to avoid computing insert/update/delete orders amongst rows.

Comment: Are you basically asking a variant of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998267/deferred-constraint-checking)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far SQL Server does not support them. What is the problem you are solving?

Comment: We have an ORM layer in our business system that takes advantage of DC in Oracle that we may want to port to SQL Server. Unfortuntely, DC doesn't seem to be supported which complicates the effort to port the implementation. In particular, the network of changes records will need to be processed in a very particular (and difficult to compute order) to avoid violating any RI constraints. Just looking for a way to avoid having to do this.

Comment: I wrote a small post about it some time ago. Basically you save draft rows in all your tables, than you mark them as finished, at which point RI turns on. Google up

"Mimicking Deferrable Constraints With Persisted Computed Columns. "

Answer (score 29):

OT: There are IMHO quite a few things SQL Server does not support, but would make sense in an enterprise environment:

- Deferrable constraints as mentioned here
- MARS: Just why do you need to set an option for something entirely natural?
- CASCADE DELETE constraints: SQL Server does only allow one single cascadation path for a given CASCADE DELETE constraint. Again, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be allowed to cascade on deletion through multiple possible paths: In the end, at the time it really is executed, there will always be only one path being actually used, so why is this restriction?
- Prevention of parallel transactions on a single ADO.NET connection.
- Forcing of every command executed on a connection that has a transaction to be executed within this transaction.
- When creating a UNIQUE index, NULL is treated as if it was an actual value, and allowed to appear only once in the index. SQL's notion of NULL as an "unknown value" would, however, indicate, that NULL values be ignored altogether when creating the index...

All these little things make many of the referential integrity and transactional features you would expect from a full-sized RDBMS nearly useless in SQL Server. For example, since deferrable constraints are not supported, the notion of a "transaction" as an externally consistent Unit Of Work is partly negated, the only viable solution - except fro some dirty workarounds - being to not define referential integrity constraints at all. I would expect, the natural behavior of a transaction be that you can work inside it in the way and order of operations you like, and the system will make sure it is consistent at the time you commit it.
Similar problems arise from the restriction, that a referential integrity constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE may only be defined in a way that only one single constraint can lead to the cascaded deletion of an object. This really doesn't fit most real-world scenarios.

Comment: You can now have unique indexes containing nulls by using a filtered index.

Comment: Complete truth, SQL Server won't allow you to write good ORM over it, unfortunately :(

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and later (and probably earlier versions too) supports MARS and Filtered Indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not.

I found about five different blog posts all saying SQLServer (in various versions) does not support Deferrable Constraints.

On the other hand, I also found a post which attempts to mimic this feature by using ["persisted computed columns,"](http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.com/2006_10_01_archive.html) (scroll to the last entry), but *caveat emptor*

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the problem you have is that SQL does not support what Date and Darwen call 'multiple assignment'. Standard SQL's response to this was 'deferrable constraints', which SQL Server does not support. A SQL Server FK or CHECK constraint can be flagged with NOCHECK but its not quite the same. For more details see MSDN: [ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you have your own ORM layer, one solution to your problem could be separating object update from reference update by the logic of your ORM layer.
Your ORM would then work with transactions based on your client-side change set in several steps:

1. Delete all foreign key references defined by your change set as being deleted, i.e. set corresponding foreign key columns to NULL, or, for relationships using mapping tables, DELETE entries from mapping tables as appropriate.
2. Delete all objects defined as "deleted" by your change sets
3. Create all new objects in your change set, but do not yet set foreign key columns
4. Update all "primitive" value changes on any updated objects in the change set, i.e. do not update foreign key columns
5. Set foreign key column values as defined in your change set.
6. Add mapping table mappings for mapping table-based relationships
7. Commit

This should solve your problem, since all objects referenced exist at any time a foreign key value is set...

Comment: Or use a stored procedure and plug that into the Insert() Update() of that Entity in the ORM (Entity Framework and Linq to SQL allows this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346601/stored-procedures-and-orms)

Answer (score 2):

There's a method to work around the missing deferred constraint enforcement *under certain conditions* (as of January 2017, there's no support for deferred constraints in SQL Server). Consider the following database schema:

*Disclaimer: The quality of the schema, or the use case, is not up for a debate here, it is given as a basic example for the workaround*

```
CREATE TABLE T (Id TYPE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NextId TYPE NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE T WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T2T 
FOREIGN KEY (NextId) REFERENCES T (Id);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UC_T ON T (NextId);
```

Where TYPE is some suitable data type for a surrogate key. The assumption is that the value for the surrogate key is assigned by the RDBMS during the INSERT operation (i.e. IDENTITY).

The use case is to keep the "latest" version of the entity T with NextId = NULL, and store the previous versions by maintaining a single-linked list T.NextId -> T.Id.

Obviously, the given schema is subject to the deferred constraint problem because the insert of the new-"latest" version must precede the update of the old-"latest" and during that time there will be two records in the database with the same NextId value.

**Now, if:**

The data type of the primary key doesn't have to be numeric, and can be calculated in advance (i.e. UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), then the deferred constraint problem is sidestepped using MERGE statement, like so:

```
DECLARE @MergeTable TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

DECLARE @NewLatestVersion UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO @MergeTable (Id) VALUES (@NewLatestVersion);
INSERT INTO @MergeTable (Id) VALUES (@OldLatestVersion);

MERGE INTO T
USING @MergeTable m ON T.Id = m.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.NextId = @NewLatestVersion
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id) VALUES (@NewLatestVersion);
```

Apparently, MERGE statement completes all data manipulations before checking the constraints.

Comment: `MERGE`'s own _kinda-deferred_ checking is officially a bug (not a feature, sorry) that [Microsoft said they'd fix in SQL Server 2012](http://web.archive.org/web/20131031173743/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/699055/merge-query-plans-allow-fk-and-check-constraint-violations) but as of 2022 I don't think this is fixed yet still - (this is a separate issue from [another `MERGE` constraint bug FK that was fixed in CU1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb956718-e4123d3d-a8b4-3bf4-9faf-485b57d693f1))

Comment: Oh, and also see the other active issues from every `MERGE` user's favourite webpage: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ - last updated 2018

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
ALTER TABLE your_table NOCHECK CONSTRAINT your_constraint
```

your action

```
ALTER TABLE your_table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Comment: This works just fine for bulk inserts. I think however it will always re-evaluate all records, so it would not be suitable for OLTP workloads.

Comment: This approach will make your connection acquire a schema-lock (`Sch-S`) on the entire table, which will prevent all other queries from anyone else from running until your connection releases the lock - so this approach is completely unsuitable for any kind of production-database under continuous use.