# Entity Framework Code First : how to annotate a foreign key for a "Default" value?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I have 2 classes: Client and Survey.

Each Client can have many surveys - but only one default survey.

I have defined the classes like this:

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> DefaultSurveyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefaultSurveyID")]
    public virtual Survey DefaultSurvey { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
}

public class Survey
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SurveyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the Client table as I expect:

```
[dbo].[Clients]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ClientName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DefaultSurveyID] [int] NULL
)
```

But the Survey table has an extra foreign key:

```
[dbo].[Surveys]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SurveyName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Client_ID] [int] NULL
)
```

Why is Code First generating this relationship and how to I tell it not to?

Comment: Different ways of modelling this problem in a database: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5244920/150342

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that when you have multiple relationships between two entities, EF Code First isn't able to find out which navigation properties match up, unless, you tell it how, here is the code:

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    /****Change Nullable<int> by int?, looks better****/
    public int? DefaultSurveyID { get; set; }

    /****You need to add this attribute****/
    [InverseProperty("ID")]
    [ForeignKey("DefaultSurveyID")]
    public virtual Survey DefaultSurvey { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
}
```

With your previous version, EF was creating that extra relationship because it didn't know that the `DefaultSurvey` property was referencing the `ID` of the `Survey` class, but you can let it know that, adding the attribute `InverseProperty` whose parameter is the name of the property in `Survey` you need `DefaultSurvey` to match with.

Comment: A client can have many surveys but only one default survey, and that survey should be in the set of surveys defined by the first relationship.

Comment: @Colin: Sorry, my bad, it was a typo, the relationships are **one-to-many**, I fixed my answer. Try the code I posted and reply.

Comment: A survey cannot be the default survey for many clients because the survey can only be linked to one client. Therefore the Survey class should not contain a ClientsDefault collection

Comment: @Colin: Sorry then, I can't see a way through :(

Comment: @Colin: I got it!!! Totally change my answer, first time I misunderstood your question, check out now!!!

Comment: The other answers are really useful, but this is the only one that answers my question in full (Why is Code First generating this relationship and how to I tell it not to?). Brilliant! Many thanks. +1 from me, and marked as the solution. :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using code-first, but not being a code first expert I cheated :-)

1) I created the tables and relationships (as above without the extra Client_ID) in the database using SMS

2) I used [Reverse Engineer Code First](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to create the required classes and mappings

3) I dropped the database and recreated it using context.Database.Create()

Original table defs:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DefaultSurveyId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Client] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Survey](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Survey] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

Plus foreign keys

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Survey]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Survey_dbo.Client_ClientId] FOREIGN KEY([ClientId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Client]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Client_dbo.Survey_DefaultSurveyId] 
    FOREIGN KEY([DefaultSurveyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Survey] ([Id])
```

Code generated by reverse engineering:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.Surveys = new List<Survey>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultSurveyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey DefaultSurvey { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
}

public partial class Survey
{
    public Survey()
    {
        this.Clients = new List<Client>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class ClientMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public ClientMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Client");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.DefaultSurveyId).HasColumnName("DefaultSurveyId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DefaultSurvey)
            .WithMany(t => t.Clients).HasForeignKey(d => d.DefaultSurveyId);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class SurveyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Survey>
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public SurveyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Survey");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.ClientId).HasColumnName("ClientId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Client)
            .WithMany(t => t.Surveys).HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution that uses the Fluent API to address the problem. It really helped me understand what can be done with the Entity Framework +1

Comment: Just giving me the link and telling me about the "EF Power Tools" was worth it's weight in gold. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework does exactly what it's told to do. What you've told it is that there is both a one-to-many and a one-to-one relationship between Clients and Surveys. It generated both FKs in the Survey table in order to map both of the relationships that you've requested. It has no idea that you're trying to connect the two relationships together, nor do I think does it have the ability to deal with that.

As an alternative you might want to consider adding a `IsDefaultSurvey` field on the Survey object so that you can query for the default survey through the `Surveys` collection that you have on the Client object. You could even go one step further and put it in as a `NotMapped` property on the Client object so that you could still use `Client.DefaultSurvey` to get the correct survey, and not have to change any of your other code, as follows:

```
[NotMapped]
public Survey DefaultSurvey
{
  get { return this.Surveys.First(s => s.IsDefaultSurvey); }
}
```

Comment: You would have to somehow tell the database which one is the default survey. You could do that as part of the edit page for the survey, and then have validation to make sure there is only one default survey on the client.

Comment: I'm not quite getting this. I've specified a one-to-many by  putting the Client and ClientID properties in the Survey class. I've specified a one-to-one by putting DefaultSurvey and DefaultSurveyID in the Client class - but there is nothing to say it's one-to-one is there? Confused....

Comment: And EF is generating 3 relationships, not just 2?

Comment: Here's how this goes: You set up the one to many by having the *collection* of `Survey` on the Client. You set up the 1:1 by having the `DefaultSurvey` field on the Client. The Client fields on the `Survey` object just serve to link up those connections.

Comment: 2 relationships: One to many on the collection, and a 1:1 on the single `DefaultSurvey` field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26393/discussion-between-colin-and-ironman84)

Comment: This is a great way to work around the problem, and some people might argue that the database schema is better because additional constraints can be added http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17456/18422. However, like some others ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/5493920/150342 ) I 'think the solution in the question expresses the "natural" relationships of the model better'. +1 for helping me understand the options available in the Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that adding the code below you will fix the issue.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
          modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
                      .HasOptional(x => x.DefaultSurvey)
                      .WithMany(x => x.Surveys);
                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.DefaultSurveyID);
    {
}
```