# EntityFramework when columnname changed error is Invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am building an MVC4 application and using Entityframework.
I am using code first model.

My Project class is as follows:

```
public class Project
    {
     [Key]
       public int ProjectId { get; set; }
       public ProjectContact ApprovalContact { get; set; }

        public ProjectContact BillContact { get; set; }

        public ProjectContact ProjectContact { get; set; }
     }
```

My ProjectContact class is as follows:

```
public class ProjectContact
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProjectContactId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string ProjectContactMSFNo { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

    }
```

While using **Code first** in **EntityFramework**  database generated is

```
SELECT [ProjectId]
      ,[ApprovalContact_ProjectId]
      ,[BillContact_ProjectId]
      ,[ProjectContact_ProjectId]
  FROM [Db].[dbo].[Projects]
```

**Till now it is working fine**

**Now** When 
I changed column **[ApprovalContact_ProjectId]** to **[ApprovalContact]**
 and try to insert project in database i get **error: Invalid column name 'ApprovalContact_ProjectContactId'.**

when i try to map model name in **modelBuilder** i get **ERROR:Models.ProjectContact must be non nullable**

How to tell **DbContext** to map **[ApprovalContact_ProjectId]** to **[ApprovalContact]**??

Comment: are you renaming [ApprovalContact_ProjectId] to [ApprovalContact] in database directly?

Comment: No.. I am changing in the migration Initial_Migration script and running it thru Package Manager Console to Update Database

Comment: May I know the reason for renaming?

Comment: My client is admant on the name...

Comment: Could you show the mapping the causes the error?

Comment: Error is "Models.ProjectContact must be non nullable"

Comment: You seem to change the database name without changing the mapping. Have you got any mapping configuration on the property, either fluent or by data annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following annotation

```
[ForeignKey("ApprovalContactID")]
public ProjectContact ApprovalContact { get; set; }
```

I have found this at : [Entity Framework Code First : how to annotate a foreign key for a "Default" value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483019/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-annotate-a-foreign-key-for-a-default-valu)

and I also suggest you to look at :
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1226