# Good design: 2 tables with a foreign key to the same primary key

Tags: database-design

I wonder whether I am following a good design for following db tables.

Tables:

- Project_Proposal
- Milestones_Proposal
- Resources_Proposal
- Project
- Milestones_Project
- Resources_Project

Both milestones tables have the same columns and both resource tables have the same columns.

My question is whether I should

1. Merge Milestones_Proposal with Milestones_Project
2. Merge Resources_Proposal with Resources_Project
3. Create a column "TYPE" to identify if the data in these tables belong to either a project or a project proposal
4. Define a foreign key in Milestones and Resources that either point to Project_Proposal or Project table depending on the "Type" value.

Design would be then like this:

- Project_Proposal
- Project
- Milestones
- Resources

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: What is the difference between Project and Project_Proposal?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same fields, but they "point" (through foreign keys) to different tables, so you can't just merge them into a single field. What you'll end-up with is a CHECK that allows one field or the other to contain a non-NULL value, based on the type field.

Which is perfectly fine in this simple case. You are essentially following the strategy #1 out of the [3 possible strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178524/533120) for implementing inheritance.