# mysql efficiency: self join versus two tables split

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, join, self-join

I'm just wondering from design, efficiency and space perspectives, what's a better choice? Self-join or using two tables and then joining them?

I have a MySQL database that stores product design details, the `designer_type` could be either `company_staff`, or a certain `customer_type`.

Initially I thought of having 2 tables, one called `staff_design` and one called `customer_design`.

Either way the `design` information remains almost the same, except that if it's a customer, there are two extra columns that the staff_design doesn't need, one which is a foreign key to the ID of a `staff_design`, and one which is `design_name` (something that users and not staff can add). Both of these 2 columns may be NULL.

So if I design the database such that these two tables are merged and there is only one `design` table, then this table will have 3 additional columns that might be NULL quite often: it'll need to have `design_type` (specifying `customer`, or `staff`), and then the two extra columns I mentioned above. (`design_name` and `staff_design` FK).

Which design is better?

I'm leaning towards the single table design mainly to reduce hard disk processing (fetching two different tables rather than one). I'll then have to use plenty of self joins.

What is considered professionally a better approach? There are expected to be thousands of designs saved by staff_designers, while only advanced and customers with an additional fee will be saving customized designs of their own. So there are certainly going to be many, many more staff designs than customer designs.

Comment: Can you add some info on the order of magnitude of the count of the records in the `design` table (in case of one table).

Comment: edited the question to add it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the order of magnitude of the records is only several thousands, I suggest to go for single table design. That will make your life easier and the size of the table does not justify the optimization of splitting the table.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes your life easier, there's nothing wrong with merging everything into 1 single table, if I understood your design well.

Especially if your Mysql database uses the Innodb engine : NULL fields [don't take space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage) (or a negligible amount, 1 bit or so).

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is essentially inheritance (aka. category, subtype, generalization hierarchy etc...).

Out of [3 possible ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178524/533120) to implement it, you are describing "all classes in one table". There is nothing wrong with that - each way has its own set of pros and cons and this one seems appropriate in your case.