# How to design this database to avoid Circular Reference between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns

I have 3 tables.

- People
- Post
- Likes

When I design ER it has Circular Reference(cyclic dependency)..

```
 1:N
```

People --------< Post

```
 1:N
```

Post ----------< Likes

```
 1:M
```

People --------< Likes

Logic is

- 1 people can have many posts.
- 1 post has many likes.
- 1 people can like many posts (created person cannot like his own
  post).

How can i remove this kind of cyclic design?? or my db design is wrong??

any suggestion.. thanks advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I don't see a circular reference.

Comment: people post and likes three are inter connected ??  is it no circular reference

Comment: No, not necessarily. You would need to post the actual data structure.

Comment: Also, your third relationship is incorrect. It's 1:N, not N:M.

Comment: different tables in MySQL. they have some attribute and each of them has id(integer value) as primary key

Comment: i corrected third  relationship.

Comment: You need to post the actual DDL. But if your structure is like the one @bcampolo posted below, then it's not a circular reference. See the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999131/avoid-circular-dependency

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which part is cyclical in your example, but the design I first thought of was this:

People
Column1: Person ID
Column2: Name

Post
Column1: Post ID
Column2: Person ID who posted

Likes
Column1: Like ID
Column2: Post ID that was liked
Column3: Person ID that liked the Post

Comment: i design like this, but i thought likes table has circular reference..i am not sure about that..when i get person from like table through post .it will load infinite data??

Comment: Nope. No infinite data. Whatever answer you're trying to obtain through your query, you can do without a circular reference.

Comment: While this is a good design, I see little purpose for the LikeId field in the likes table.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - true, it is not needed, but provides a primary key that may later be used as the FK in another table or as a resource identifier in a RESTful service.