# Single Relation M:N for unknow element number

Tags: mysql, database-design, relation

Currently I have an article with various M:N relations with other elements, the problem is that these elements can and will grow up and not want to have that amount of tables in my database.

[image]

which is the right way to build a single relationship M: N for an unknown number of elements

Comment: Why not having these tables in your database? Apparently your fonctional environment limits the magnitute by itself; I don't really see you having more than a few more tables than these (~ 40/50 is not so much). Don't forget that denormalising has a price.

Comment: I mean I do not want lots of tables category, article_category, author, article_author, other, article_other when this tables has the same structure (id, name)

Comment: you could make one table then, (article_id, object_id, object_name), object_name being the name of the table your relate the article to

Comment: @rkmax: one of my database programs started like this - I had several tables, each denoting a different entity, all of which initially had two fields, id and name. But as time went on, I needed extra functionality and so most tables had fields added. I think it's best to have different tables, even though they apparently have the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the right way to build a single relationship M: N for an unknown number of elements

There is nothing particularly wrong with having separate junction table for each of the M:N relationships.

That being said, you can handle these relationships in a more generic way, and at the same time lower the number of tables by using inheritance<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

For more information about the concept of inheritance, search for "Subtype Relationships" in [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF). For some hints at how the inheritance can be implemented in a relational database, take a look at:

- [How to create multiple one to one's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178524/533120)
- [Interpreting ER diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120)

---

*<sup>1</sup> Aka. category, subclassing, subtyping, generalization hierarchy...*

Comment: I had read about this a while, have some link about inheritance in Doctrine2

Answer (score 0):

If all elements would have same attributes You could keep them all in one table with extra column(enum best) to distinguish between them.

But looking at image You provided they probably don't have same attributes so it would be difficult and inefficient to somehow force them to be in one or just few tables.

There is no limit on number of tables You may create and I have no idea why should You avoid creating a new table for each relation as it should be.