# Enforce unique entry across multiple tables

Tags: database-design

I have a table structure with several 0 to 1 relationships.

1 Resource can have

**0 to 1** Temporary Codes
**0 to 1** Permanent Codes **OR** **0 to 1** Store Credits

I'm looking for a way to ensure at the database level that an entry cannot exist in both the permanent code table **AND** the store credit table.  (it should produce an error - as if a duplicate key were being added)

Can anyone think of a design that would ensure this?  Or should I use a stored procedure?

Any advice would be appreciated!

**edit**: To be clear - what I want to ensure is that if I try to insert an entry into Permanent Codes **AND** Store Credits - this would violate some kind of database rule (Produce an error).  In other words, it should be impossible to have both.

Comment: See [How to create multiple one to one's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9178524/533120).

Comment: Why not use the same column for all? Treat like a bitflag setup. Where 1's can be temp codes, 2's can be permanent codes, and 4's to be store credits. So `b'000` would be all 0's, and `b'100` be Store credit.