# Are there any options to a join table for many-to-many associations?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have two tables with data that isn't supposed to change through the use of my application (i.e. domain tables) for something like the **model of a car** and the **color of a car.**

The `models` table lists different types of car models that exist.

The `colors` table lists different types of colors that a car can come in.

Now, it might not be evident right away, but there exists a relationship between the two. A **color** may only be available for a certain model, or more likely several models of the same make. A **model** certainly doesn't come in a specific color, but it does come with a selection, or choice, of colors that I do want to store in the database.

So there exists a many-to-many relationship between them, which suggests that I should store the details of that relationship in a join table. So, if you forgive my own notation, it would look something like this:

```
Volvo V70 <-> Pearl White
Volvo V70 <-> Emerald Green
Volvo V70 <-> Night Black
Volvo V70 <-> Salmon Pink
Volvo V70 <-> Ocean Blue
Volvo V70 <-> Raspberry Red

Volvo V60 <-> Pearl White
Volvo V60 <-> Emerald Green
Volvo V60 <-> Night Black
Volvo V60 <-> Salmon Pink
Volvo V60 <-> Ocean Blue
Volvo V60 <-> Raspberry Red

...
```

This is A LOT of repeated text. Easier would be if I could just do

```
[Volvo V70, V60, S60, S40] <-> [Pearl White, Emerald Green, Night Black, Salmon Pink, Ocean Blue, Raspberry Red]
```

and move on to the next car model and set of colors.

Are there any options to a regular join table that can simplify this process in any way?

Comment: Do not use text in join table - use ids. And "a lot of repeated text" will become _a lot of relationships_, which is the case you have. This is the design you want.

Comment: As I said, it's my own notation and I will use id's. If I made it with id's here the point wouldn't come across.

Comment: Are you asking for a model to reduce some redundancy, or just a method to simplify your model's initial population?

Comment: @pozs Anything, really. I hoped there'd be another way, but I guess now that this is what most would do in my case? I'm working with Rails by the way.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson you don't have to worry about some redundancy, if you are working with numeric primary keys (aka. `id`s) and not with texts. -- You could create a table like `color_groups` and make the relation like `[model] *<-->* [color_groups] *<-->* [color]`, but that will only reduce the redundancy, if you have (and will always have) clear, separated color groups. But that way, you'll have a headache, if f.ex. some time later Volvo will have a series like S99 with all the colors above, but *Emerald Green*: you will need to create another color_group entry for that series only.

Comment: @pozs Didn't quite get what you mean but yeah the last drawback sounds like it wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If models don't share colour groups then the design would be one table:

  ```
  model [model] comes in color [color]
  ```
- If models share colour groups then have two tables:

  ```
  model [model] comes in the colors of group [group]
  group [group] has color [color]
  ```

  These tables join with projection to the first table:

  ```
  SELECT model, color FROM model_group NATURAL JOIN group_color
  ```
- If a model can have exceptional available and/or unavailable colours in addition to or instead of a group then have exception tables. A table's group is now its *default* colours (if any):

  ```
  model [model] has default color group [group]
  group [group] has color [color]
  model [model] is exceptionally available in color [color]
  model [model] is exceptionally unavailable in color [color]
  ```

  The exception tables are then respectively UNIONed with and MINUSed/EXCEPTed from a JOIN-plus-PROJECT/SELECT to give the first table:

  ```
  SELECT group, color FROM model_default NATURAL JOIN group_colour
  EXCEPT SELECT * FROM model_unavailable
  UNION SELECT * FROM model_available
  ```

"Redundancy" is not about values appearing in multiple places. It is about multiple rows stating the same thing about the application.

Every table (and query expression) has an associated fill-in-the-(named-)blanks statement template (aka predicate). The rows that make a true statement go in the table. If you have two independent predicates then you need two tables. The relevant values go in the rows of each one.

Re rows making statements about the application see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682724/3404097). (And search my other answers re a table's "statement" or "criterion".) Normalization helps because it replaces tables whose rows state things of the form "... AND ..." by other tables that state the "..." separately. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24422479/3404097J) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228285/3404097).

If you share groups and only use a single two-column table for model and color then its predicate is:

```
FOR SOME group
    model [model] comes in the colors of group [group]
AND group [group] has color [color]
```

So the second bullet removes a single "AND" from this predicate, ie the source of a "multivalued dependency". Otherwise if you change a model's group or a group's colours then you have to simultaneously consistently change multiple rows. (The point is to reduce errors and complexity from redundancy, not save space.)

If you don't want to repeat the *strings* for implementation(-dependent) reasons (space taken or speed of operations at the expense of more joins) then add a table of name ids and strings and replace your old name columns and values by id columns and values. (That's not normalization, that's complicating your schema for the sake of implementation-dependent data optimization tradeoffs. And you should *demonstrate* this is needed and works.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Grouping the colors from the get-go is a good idea, even though I don't know to deal with exceptions (I don't write SQL). Might I perchance suggest something to you? You have a way of typing that makes things very hard to follow, so I had to read the first part a few times before I grasped what you meant, and the second part went completely over my head, as well as your other posts (of which I literally understood nothing). So if you want newbies like me to grasp your concepts, use a less syntax-heavy language and, I don't know, pretend you talk to a moron or something.

Comment: I coincidentally just edited my answer. Thanks for the comments. I will apply your suggestions. I expect that besides grammar 1. there's a lot of new & fundametal ideas and 2. the messages are dense. (Not you!)

Answer (score 1):

When modeling a many to many relationship, as Kleskowy stated in the comments, you need one entry in the join table per relationship (model <-> color).

You could reproduce your example in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE car_model(car_model_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, model_name text NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE car_color(car_color_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, color_name text NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE join_model_color(
  car_model_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES car_model(car_model_id),
  car_color_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES car_color(car_color_id),
  CONSTRAINT model_color_unique_entries UNIQUE(car_model_id, car_color_id)
);
```

Then to insert your data:

```
INSERT INTO car_model(model_name) SELECT 'Volvo V70' UNION SELECT 'Volvo V60';
INSERT INTO car_color(color_name) SELECT 'Pearl White' UNION SELECT 'Emerald Green' UNION SELECT 'Night Black' UNION SELECT 'Salmon Pink' UNION SELECT 'Ocean Blue' UNION SELECT 'Raspberry Red';
INSERT INTO join_model_color SELECT car_model_id, car_color_id FROM car_model, car_color WHERE model_name = 'Volvo V70' AND color_name IN ('Pearl White', 'Emerald Green', 'Night Black', 'Salmon Pink', 'Ocean Blue', 'Raspberry Red');
INSERT INTO join_model_color SELECT car_model_id, car_color_id FROM car_model, car_color WHERE model_name = 'Volvo V60' AND color_name IN ('Pearl White', 'Emerald Green', 'Night Black', 'Salmon Pink', 'Ocean Blue', 'Raspberry Red');
```

Then you can query your data for example like this:

```
SELECT color_name FROM car_model NATURAL INNER JOIN join_model_color NATURAL INNER JOIN car_color WHERE model_name = 'Volvo V70';
SELECT model_name FROM car_model NATURAL INNER JOIN join_model_color NATURAL INNER JOIN car_color WHERE color_name = 'Emerald Green';
```

Comment: So there is no other way?

Comment: Of course you could design it in other ways (e.g. the way you suggested), but you would probably end up with more duplication and/or less efficient queries (try writing analogies to the SELECT-Queries from the answer in your model).

Comment: But the way I suggested is the same as yours?

Comment: I mean the end result.

Comment: In both cases no information is being lost, if that is what you mean. It's just that your way bundles some of that information up (in color-groups and car-groups), so querying for a subset of these is going to be more complex. If you are really worried about too many entries in a join table (I would not be), @pozs suggestion would only create marginally more data then your original approach, but be almost as easily accessible as the simple mapping I suggested (with the caveat he mentions about future changes).

Comment: I'm confused. You explicitly states that you're only reproducing my example, but now you say the end result is different as well as the method? But I'm glad to hear you say you're not too worried. However, I will have to have like 20 or 30 join tables like this, that's the reason for my concern. Lots of data to put in.

Comment: I reproduced the intent (first part of the question), not the grouping of cars and colors you proposed (see @philipxy's answer for that, which minimizes data duplication even further than pozs comment suggests).