# Database modelling for 2 many-to-many realations

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 3 entities

`teacher` : Stores the name of a teacher in the school. (e.g "teacher 1", "teacher 2")
`access` : Stores the name of all types type of access possible. (e.g "class_teacher", "sports_teacher", "head_master")
`classroom`: Stores the name of different classes in the school. (e.g. "classroom I", "classroom II")

The relationships are as follows:

- teacher <-> access is many-to-many
- teacher <-> classroom is many-to-many

The way I have modelled it right now is in following tables

1. Teacher (id, username)  (1 t1, 2 t2)
2. access  (id, access)  (1 a1, 2 a2)
3. classroom (id, class) (1 c1, 2 c2)
4. teacher_access (id, teacherId, accessId) (1 1 1, 1 1 2)
5. teacher_classroom (id, teacherId, classroomId)  (1 1 1, 1 1 2)

A row in teacher_access stores the specific "access" a specific "teacher" has.
e.g. (1 1 1) shows that t1 has access a1

A row in teacher_classroom allows a specific "teacher" to access a specific "classroom" using the accesses he/she has.
e.g. (1 1 1) shows that teacher t1 has access to classroom c1

The problem here is that I don't want to give teacher t1 access a2 for classroom c2.

In my current design, if there is a row in teacher_access, the tId in that row will have the "access" specified by this row's aId for all the classrooms for which we have a row in "teacher_classroom" having the same teacherId. So, if I have 2 rows in "teacher_access" with (tId =1, aId = 1), (tId = 1, aId = 2) and 2 rows in "teacher_classroom" with (tId =1, cId =1),(tId = 1, cId = 2), "teacher"(1) has both "accesses"(1,2) for both "classrooms"(1,2). But what I want to do is provide only aId(1) to tId(1) for cId(1) and both aId (1,2) for cId (2) tId : teacherId aId : accessId cId: classroomId.

What I am trying to say is I want a "teacher" to have different "accesses" to different "classrooms". E.g. A teacher can have both "class_teacher" and "sports_teacher" access to classroom "classroom I" and only "sports_teacher" access to "classroom II". I am unable to do this using my current design because if a teacher has "access" (sports_teacher, class_teacher) per teacher_access and the same teacher has access to "classroom" (classroom I, classroom II), I cannot have the teacher as only "sports_teacher" for "classroom II".

What is a better way to model?

Comment: Do not have an `id` in a many-to-many table.  Instead, have `PRIMARY KEY(teacherId, accessId), INDEX(accessId, teacherId)`.  (And use InnoDB.)

Comment: In my current design, if there is a row in teacher_access, the tId in that row will have  the "access" specified by this row's aId for all the classrooms for which we have a row in "teacher_classroom" having the same teacherId.  

So, if I have 2 rows in "teacher_access" with (tId =1, aId = 1), (tId = 1, aId = 2) and 2 rows in "teacher_classroom" with (tId =1, cId =1),(tId = 1, cId = 2), "teacher"(1) has both "accesses"(1,2) for both "classrooms"(1,2)

what I want to do is provide only aId(1) to tId(1) for cId(1). and both aId (1,2) for cId (2)

tId : teacherId 
aId : accessId
cId: classroomId

Comment: I would like to help you, but you are not being clear about how the access system works so I can't make sense of what tables you ought to have. Repeating part of my last comment: Please be more clear. Use more words. Explain it the way you would to a new teacher who doesn't know the system. Because we don't know the system. Please don't talk about tables because you have not managed to be clear about what a row means when it is in each of them.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. What I am trying to say is I want a "teacher" to have different "accesses" to different "classrooms".  
e.g. A teacher can have both "class_teacher" and "sports_teacher" access to classroom "classroom I" and only "sports_teacher" access to "classroom II"

I am unable to do this using my current design because if a teacher has "access"(sports_teacher, class_teacher) using teacher_access and the same teacher has access to "classroom" (classroom I, classroom II), I cannot have the teacher as only "sports_teacher" for "classroom II". Does this make sense ?

Comment: I moved my latest comments to my answer. (Meanwhile you accepted it.) PS Please edit relevant comments into your question. PPS A database reflects a situation. So in the current design teacher_class holds rows satisfying "FOR SOME ACCESS, id ID ids teacher TEACHER_ID having access ACCESS for classroom CLASSROOM" ie "id ID ids teacher TEACHER_ID having some access for classroom CLASSROOM". The phrasing "teacher t1 has access to classroom c1" doesn't make sense because "having access" is something that involves a teacher, an access and a classroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe what is going on via teacher, access, classroom and a table for

```
"teacher TID has access AID to classroom CID"
```

Accorinding to your edits and comments: Given a teacher or an access or a classroom, there isn't just one value for the rest of a row. Given a teacher and classroom, there could be multiple accesses. Given a teacher and access, there could be multipe rooms. Given an access and room, there could be multiple teachers. So you cannot describe a school situation as a JOIN of components. (That relationship is "all (candidate) key".)

You might be able to describe the situation in fewer numbers if you describe defaults and exceptions.

PS See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358446/3404097) re defaults and exceptional additions & subtractions.

---

(Some guesses at solutions arising from earlier edits of your question follow. I use some new table names although some tables with new names might end up being some of your old tables. I use minimal ids.)

Maybe you only need two entity tables and a many-to-many table:

```
teacher "TEACHER identifies a teacher named NAME"
classroom "CLASSROOM identifies a classroom"
has_access "teacher TEACHER has access to classroom CLASSROOM"
    FK (TEACHER) references teacher
    FK (CLASSROOM) references classroom
```

To also record actual permitted accessings:

```
is_accessing "teacher TEACHER is accessing classroom CLASSROOM"
    FK (TEACHER, CLASSROOM) references teacher_access
```

On the other hand maybe an "access" is 1:1 with a set of classrooms and having an access means accessing those rooms is permitted. This situation can be recorded in the above database. But it can be organized less redundantly as follows.

```
teacher "TEACHER identifies a teacher named NAME"
classroom "CLASSROOM identifies a classroom"
access "ACCESS identifies an access"

access_classroom "access ACCESS acesses classroom CLASSROOM"
    FK (ACCESS) references access
    FK (CLASSROOM) references classroom
teacher_access "teacher TEACHER has access ACCESS"
    FK (TEACHER) references teacher
    FK (ACCESS) references access
```

Now

```
has_access "teacher TEACHER has access to classroom CLASSROOM"
```

is

```
select TEACHER, CLASSROOM
from teacher_access natural join access_classroom
```

To also record actual permitted accessings:

```
is_accessing "teacher TEACHER is accessing classroom CLASSROOM"
```

Then we would still like to have:

```
    FK (TEACHER, CLASSROOM) references has_access
```

But in most DBMSs this cannot be enforced declaratively.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is that I can't have different "accesses" for different "classrooms" for a single "teacher". If a teacher has access to a "classroom", he has access to all its "accesses" from access_classroom.

Answer (score 0):

The way your model is right now a teacher either has access to a recource or not. What you need to do is set up a relation table that connects all three entities. E.g. teacher_room_access(id, teacherId, classId, accessId)(1 1 1 1, 2 1 1 2, 3 2 1 1, 4 2 2 2)

Comment: In that case, I have an entry for each "access" a "teacher" has to a "class". so if I have 300 classes, there are 300 rows with same data. isn't that denormalisation ?