# Database/Application Design for Group-able Entity

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, architecture

Just want to ask for an input for what's the best database/application design for the following scenario

1. I have a table called `computers`
2. Each products can be grouped by the following:

   - `vendor` (e.g. 'Sony', 'Apple','HP'),
   - `type` (e.g. 'laptop','personal desktop','server')
   - `size` (e.g. 'small','medium','large')`
   - more things to come as the business requirement changes (maybe `touchscreen` in the future)
3. These computers can be grouped to certain `repairers` when

   - 'PC Repairers' can fix small `personal desktops` and `small laptops`
   - 'Better Computers' can fix `all Sony computers`
   - 'Repair for Less' can fix `all HP servers` but not the `large`
4. As you can see there may be chances that things can be overlapped

   - Small Sony laptops can be fixed by both 'PC Repairers' and 'Better Computers'

What is the term for this kind of database design? I do not even know how to search it online

Would love to hear your answers !

Thanks

Comment: You are just talking about a bunch of "join tables" or "association tables", ie binary many:many relation(ships). If (you demonstrate that) you don't want to use DDL to create & drop tables, you can learn about (the pros and cons of) EAV.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning EAV, I learn a new term today. I'm still looking forward to listen for design answers thou :)

Comment: Please give a design or designs of your own as a basis. Right now you are asking either for someone to do your work or a precis on information modeling. You could start by thinking clearly about what you mean by "overlapped" and how you could define it and give an example of it.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to do this properly and it's going to be a fresh database/application. This is why I ask for help. I think I already give the example of overlapping on no 3. But sure, I'll edit to give more example on step 4

Comment: Re 'overlapping': This is a word you have chosen to use because you have a vague impression. You have not defined it. You have not said what about what situations is "overlapping" what. Examples suggest or illustrate but unless you tell us what "overlapping" means we cannot know what an example is an example of.

Comment: Re an initial design: Please give some design that allows you to describe the situations that can arise. Eg `vendor(V,..)--vendor V is a vendor and ...; type(T,..) -- T is a type of computer and ...; ...; repairs_all(R,T,...) -- R can repair all computers of type T and ...; repairs_sized (R,T,S,...) --...; ...` See [this answer involving groups of things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28358446/3404097).

Comment: I'm sorry Sir, but I fail to understand  your comment (my problem not yours)... I can only explain it in a business way as I do not understand the technical way of explaining it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I am *using* the business way: Explaining what you mean by a word that you are using in only a vague way (comment re overlapping), and telling the user what a row says about the situation when it is in a table (comments guessed at re initial design). Good luck. (PS You can always ask about the first thing that you don't understand.)

Comment: @philipxy By overlapped I believe he means that there's a transitive many-to-many relationship between computers and repairers via the features-vs-abilities relation that he wants modeled.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I'm actually still looking at EAV as we speak. Appreciate your time on this. Edit: missed your comment @reaanb Thanks for helping me explain as well

Comment: @reaanb I think they mean that an overlap happens when two repairers can repair the same computer, ie the repairers' lists of computers "overlap", ie that for Repairs(repairer,vendor) a vendor can have many repairers in addition to a repairer being able to repair for many vendors, which they (mistakenly) think they stated earlier. (So it has candidate key {repairer, vendor} rather than just {vendor}.) (Which is at least something like your comment, but you haven't defined "overlaps".) But that's moot, because it's their effort to pin down their thinking that's going to help them.

Comment: @philipxy Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a name for the kind of design you're describing.  I might call it feature-based association.

If your rules require only equality of a subset of features, you could use the following schema to implement it:

```
computers (id PK, vendor, type, size)
repairers (id PK, name)
can_repair (id PK, repairer_id FK, vendor NULL, type NULL, size NULL)
```

The `can_repair` table would be used to associate repairers with the classes of computers they can repair.  Note that it doesn't handle exclusions (e.g. "all HP servers but not the large"), only inclusions (e.g. "small HP servers" and "medium HP servers").

An example of how to query for all repairers for a given computer:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.*
FROM computers c
INNER JOIN can_repair cr
    ON COALESCE(cr.vendor, c.vendor) = c.vendor
    AND COALESCE(cr.type, c.type) = c.type
    AND COALESCE(cr.size, c.size) = c.size
INNER JOIN repairers r ON cr.repairer_id = r.id
WHERE c.id = 123
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/434d21/2) to demonstrate it.

Note that this is just a proof of concept.  In the real world I would record vendor keys instead of names and represent vendors and repairers as subtypes of organizations.  I would also use enums or lookup tables for each feature rather than varchars.

**Edit**: you can add exclusions to the model easily.  Add a table:

```
cant_repair (id PK, repairer_id FK, vendor NULL, type NULL, size NULL)
```

then modify the query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.*
FROM computers c
INNER JOIN can_repair cr
    ON COALESCE(cr.vendor, c.vendor) = c.vendor
    AND COALESCE(cr.type, c.type) = c.type
    AND COALESCE(cr.size, c.size) = c.size
INNER JOIN repairers r ON cr.repairer_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN cant_repair xr
    ON xr.repairer_id = r.id
    AND COALESCE(xr.vendor, c.vendor) = c.vendor
    AND COALESCE(xr.type, c.type) = c.type
    AND COALESCE(xr.size, c.size) = c.size
WHERE c.id = 123 AND xr.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exclusion is unfortunately is part of the problem that I need to tackle and by setting the 'feature'  (im using your word, correct me if I'm wrong) as a table column, I need to change the database structure everytime I need to add/remove them. Thus this is not really a preferrable solution for me

Comment: Supporting exclusions is easy enough while the model is simple (i.e. 1NF, nulls notwithstanding).  Altering the tables when required is simple too.  If you want to extend this to use EAV tables, feel free to do so, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will wait for a bit to see if there are other answers but your argument does sound convincing regarding the simplicity of things that I don't want to do