# Sql error on update : The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `patient_address`, which reference a PK key in `patient` table. But if I try to run one of the following statements :

```
update patient set id_no='7008255601088' where id_no='8008255601089'
update patient_address set id_no='7008255601088' where id_no='8008255601089'
```

I get this error message:

> "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
> "FK__patient_a__id_no__27C3E46E". The conflict occurred in database
> "PMS", table "dbo.patient_address", column 'id_no'."      or "The
> UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK__patient_a__id_no__27C3E46E". The conflict occurred in database
> "PMS", table "dbo.patient", column 'id_no'." .

Does any body know the possible cause ? Thanks.

Comment: The column `dbo.patient_address.id_no` allows `NULL`s ? If yes, then you could SET `dbo.patient_address.id_no` to NULL, update the `dbo.patient.id_no` and then SET `dbo.patient_address.id_no` to the new value.

Comment: Yes. Is this the possible cause?

Comment: No. It isn't the cause. Is the solution.

Comment: The problem was a cascade thing in Answer 4. I'm sorted now. Thank you

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This error is encountered when the primary key of a table is updated but it is referenced by a foreign key from another table and the update specific is set to No action. The No action is the default option.

If this is your case and No action is set on the update operation you can change the foreign-key definition to Cascade.

Right click your foreign key and select **Modify**. In the Foreign key relationships dialog under the INSERT and UPDATE specifics set the UPDATE rule on Cascade:

[image]

You can also set the rule using T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP Constraint Your_FK
GO

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT [New_FK_Constraint]
FOREIGN KEY (YourColumn) REFERENCES ReferencedTable(YourColumn)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have set the 'ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE' as you have advised here. Still I am getting the same error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KushanRandima Make sure you update the primary key table, not the dependent one. For example, if Order references User, do `UPDATE User SET Id = ...`, not `UPDATE Order SET UserID = ....`

Comment: Saved me the effort of dropping all constraints and recreating them after the update statement. Timesaver!

Comment: How do you open that foreign key relationship dialog in Visual Studio 2019? Anyone?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai That dialog is from SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to change your table structure, you can run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [UserStore] 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserStore_User_UserId

ALTER TABLE [UserIdentity]
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT  FK_UserIdentity_User_UserId

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  [user] 
SET Id = 10
WHERE Id = 9

UPDATE  [dbo].[UserStore]
SET UserId = 10
WHERE UserId = 9

UPDATE  [dbo].UserIdentity
SET UserId = 10
WHERE UserId = 9

COMMIT TRAN

ALTER TABLE [UserStore] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserStore_User_UserId

ALTER TABLE UserIdentity 
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserIdentity_User_UserId
```

Comment: Is this just the example or why are two constraints deactivated?

Answer (score 5):

It sometimes happens when you try to `Insert/Update` an entity while the `foreign key` that you are trying to `Insert/Update` actually **does not exist**. So, be sure that the `foreign key` exists and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;

UPDATE patient INNER JOIN patient_address 
ON patient.id_no=patient_address.id_no 
SET patient.id_no='8008255601088', 
patient_address.id_no=patient.id_no 
WHERE patient.id_no='7008255601088';
```

Note that foreign_key_checks only temporarily set foreign key checking false. So it need to execute every time before update statement. We set it 0 as if we update parent first then that will not be allowed as child may have already that value. And if we update child first then that will also be not allowed as parent may not have that value from which we are updating. So we need to set foreign key check. 
Another thing is that if you are using command line tool to use this query then put care to mention spaces in place where i put new line or ENTER in code. As command line take it in one line, so it may happen that two words stick as patient_addressON which create syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution for me:

```
-- Check how it is now
select * from patient
select * from patient_address

-- Alter your DB
alter table patient_address nocheck constraint FK__patient_a__id_no__27C3E46E
update patient 
set id_no='7008255601088'
where id_no='8008255601088'

alter table patient_address nocheck constraint FK__patient_a__id_no__27C3E46E
update patient_address 
set id_no='7008255601088'
where id_no='8008255601088'

-- Check how it is now
select * from patient
select * from patient_address
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is as @MilicaMedic says. Alternative solution is disable all constraints, do the update and then enable the constraints again like this. Very useful when updating test data in test environments.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

update patient set id_no='7008255601088' where id_no='8008255601088'
update patient_address set id_no='7008255601088' where id_no='8008255601088'

exec sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/161410/3850405

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you change the `id_no`, some of the foreign keys would not reference anything, thus the constraint violation.
You could add `initialy deffered` to the foreign keys, so the constraints are checked when the changes are commited

Comment: According to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998095/deferrable-constraints-in-sql-server, SQL Server doesn't support Deffered. Is this true ? I was busy figuring out how to apply Deffered on foreign keys

Comment: It depends on the server, i think postgrsql supports it. For other servers, i dont know

Comment: Unfortunately my server doesn't support postgrsql.

Answer (score 0):

I would not change the constraints, 
instead, you can insert a new record in the table_1 with the primary key (id_no = 7008255601088). This is nothing but a duplicate row of the id_no = 8008255601088. so now patient_address with the foreign key constraint (id_no = 8008255601088)  can be updated to  point to the record with the new ID(ID which needed to be updated), which is updating the id_no to id_no =7008255601088.

Then you can remove the initial primary key row with id_no =7008255601088.

Three steps include:

1. Insert duplicate row for new id_no
2. Update Patient_address to point to new duplicate row
3. Remove the row with old id_no