# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, visual-studio-2019

The full error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: the UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK__Product__Categor__1FCDBCEB\". The conflict occurred in database \"dbi416547_i416547\", table \"dbo.Category\", column 'CategoryID'.

Now I tried looking it up and found: [Sql error on update : The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856420/sql-error-on-update-the-update-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-const)

But I don't know how to modify the foreign key in visual studio 2019. Also I don't understand where I would put the rule using T-SQL, because my table goes like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] 
(
    [ProductID]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Price]       DECIMAL(18)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [Photo]       NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Likes]       INT          NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID] ASC),

    FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryID])
);
```

And if I put it underneath or between the ( ) I still get errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look like at first you need to insert data into category table.

Comment: @RohanRao Nope - adding the same row twice to Product would **not** cause this FK error.

Comment: The problem is not with the table and its definition. The problem lies within your code (presumably) which you do not show. You provided a value for CategoryID that does not exist in your Category table.

Comment: Yeah, the problem lied in the fact that CategoryID was converted from enums and since enums start with 0 it gave an error, thanks :p