# Update Statement Error - SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint When I Try To Edit

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want users to be able to edit what they already created and save the changes to the db. When I test editing out, I get this error:

[image]

SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_REPTILES_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "PetAdoptDB", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column "Id"

I tried modifying the foreign key to cascade instead of no action which I found here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856420/sql-error-on-update-the-update-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-const), but, I still get the error.

While debugging I noticed that the ApplicationUser is null and ApplicationUserId equals 0 when running

```
_context.Update(reptile);
```

Not sure if that's the problem or not and if so, how to fix it.

Comment: You need to retrieve applicationuser first, set it in your entity reptile then call the update on your dbcontext.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, instead post the text as its much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry about that, will edit.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Trying your way, just having a hard time getting the applicationuser that created the reptile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using `<input type="hidden" asp-for="ApplicationUserId" />` within the form on the edit page.