# Stored procedure foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know if I am using the correct syntax but I am attempting to enter into 1 table, and then another table which has a foreign key. The primary key from `tbl1SentEmails` is used as a foreign key into `tbl1Recipients`. I've put this in a stored procedure however, I keep getting an error stating foreign key constraint. Is there a way to fix this?

Stored Procedure code:

```
-- This is the sample script to test the SP
-- An instance of the Table parameter type is created
Declare @SampelData As [dbo].[SampleDataType]
Declare @RecData As [dbo].[SampleRecType]


Insert Into @SampelData(strEmailSendID, dtmSent, strSubject, strBody, strConversationID, strConversationTopic, strConversationIndex, dtmReplied, dtmOpened, dtmClicked, blnTrackOpens, blnTrackClicks, blnTrackReplies, lngMergeID, blnHide)
Values ('ce4d29160fae4eba92c7d233723f6f59', '2016-11-08', 'strSubject', 'strBody','strConversationID', 'strConversationTopic', 'strConversationIndex', '2016-11-08', '2016-11-08', '2016-11-08', 'true', 'true', 'true', 69164, 'true')
SELECT * FROM @SampelData
Insert Into RecData(strEmailSendID, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType) 
Values ('ce4d29160fae4eba92c7d233723f6f59','dutta@standss.com.fj','Alvindra Dutt','TO')
Select * From @RecData
-- we then call the SP to store the values
Exec SampleProcedure @SampelData,@RecData
```

I'll be invoking this stored procedure from an MVC application, so I'm just passing in the raw values for the PK for `tbl1SentEmails`. However, is there anyway I can get the `strEmailSendID` of the table passed in and then enter that into `tbl1Recipients`?

This is the create for the Table Types:

```
-- Create a table data type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SampleDataType] As Table
(
--This type has structure similar to the DB table 
--SampleString Nvarchar(64) Not Null -- Having one String
--, SampleDate Date -- and one Date
strEmailSendID nvarchar(255) not null, 
dtmSent datetime not null,
strSubject nvarchar(255) null, 
strBody nvarchar(255) null, 
strConversationID nvarchar(255) null, 
strConversationTopic nvarchar(1000) null, 
strConversationIndex nvarchar(max) null, 
dtmReplied datetime null, 
dtmOpened datetime null, 
dtmClicked datetime null, 
blnTrackOpens bit null, 
blnTrackClicks bit null, 
blnTrackReplies bit null, 
lngMergeID bigint not null, 
blnHide bit null, 
lngLatestEventID bigint null, 
strClickRespone nvarchar(50) null, 
dtmClickResponse datetime null
)


CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SampleRecType] As Table
(
strEmailSendID nvarchar(255) not null, 
strEmailAddress nvarchar(255) not null, 
strDisplayName nvarchar(255) null, 
strRecipientType nvarchar(5) not null
)
```

Code for the actual stored procedure:

```
--This is the Stored Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProcedure]
(
-- which accepts one table value parameter. 
-- It should be noted that the parameter is readonly
@Sample As [dbo].[SampleDataType] Readonly, @Rec As [dbo].[SampleRecType]    ReadOnly
)
AS

Begin
-- We simply insert values into the DB table from the parameter
-- The table value parameter can be used like a table with only read rights

--Insert Into SampleTable(SampleString,SampleDate)
--Select SampleString,SampleDate From @Sample
Insert Into tbl1Recipients(strEmailSendID, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType)
Select * From @Rec
Insert Into tbl1SentEmails(strEmailSendID, dtmSent, strSubject, strBody, strConversationID, strConversationTopic, strConversationIndex, dtmReplied, dtmOpened, dtmClicked, blnTrackOpens, blnTrackClicks, blnTrackReplies, lngMergeID, blnHide, lngLatestEventID, strClickResponse, dtmClickResponse)
Select * From @Sample 
End
```

Code for the tables:

```
USE [standss_tracking_us_sandbox]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl1Recipients]    Script Date: 10/11/2016    5:24:52 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl1Recipients](
[strEmailSendID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[lngRecipientNo] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[strEmailAddress] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[strDisplayName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[strRecipientType] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl1Recipients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[strEmailSendID] ASC,
[lngRecipientNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl1Recipients]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_tbl1Recipients_tbl1SentEmails] FOREIGN KEY([strEmailSendID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl1SentEmails] ([strEmailSendID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl1Recipients] CHECK CONSTRAINT    [FK_tbl1Recipients_tbl1SentEmails]
GO


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl1SentEmails]    Script Date: 10/11/2016     5:28:42 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl1SentEmails](
[strEmailSendID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[dtmSent] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[strSubject] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[strBody] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[strConversationID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[strConversationTopic] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[strConversationIndex] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[dtmReplied] [datetime] NULL,
[dtmOpened] [datetime] NULL,
[dtmClicked] [datetime] NULL,
[blnTrackOpens] [bit] NULL,
[blnTrackClicks] [bit] NULL,
[blnTrackReplies] [bit] NULL,
[ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[lngMergeID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[blnHide] [bit] NULL,
[lngLatestEventID] [bigint] NULL,
[strClickResponse] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[dtmClickResponse] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl1SentEmails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[strEmailSendID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl1SentEmails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    [FK_tbl1SentEmails_tbl1Merges] FOREIGN KEY([lngMergeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl1Merges] ([lngMergeID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl1SentEmails] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_tbl1SentEmails_tbl1Merges]
GO
```

Comment: show us the create tables? and not sure where you get the error.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I get the error on the second `INSERT` statement when I want to insert into the `tbl1Recipients`. There is one field called `strEmailSendID` which is the PK for `tbl1SentEmails`, and acts as a FK into `tbl1Recipients`

Comment: The statement you provide includes only inserts into table variables, not into `tbl1Recipients` or `tbl1SentEmails`

Comment: why you SP doesnt receive paramaters?

Comment: So the inserts into `tbl1Recipients` and `tbl1SentEmails` happen inside the store procedure? Could you provide the code for that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it looks like the stored procedure takes table-valued parameters

Comment: @mendosi, I've updated everything I got for the stored proc and the table-valued parameters.

Comment: Now we need the create table for tblReipients and tblSentEmail because there is where the constrain are

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I created the table(s) using the designer I don't have the code for that.

Comment: You go to the sql managment studio right click the table and select create script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your stored procedure as below. It will work for you

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProcedure]
(
   @Sample As [dbo].[SampleDataType] Readonly,
   @Rec As [dbo].[SampleRecType]    ReadOnly
)
AS
Begin

    Insert Into tbl1SentEmails(strEmailSendID, dtmSent, strSubject, strBody, strConversationID, strConversationTopic, strConversationIndex, dtmReplied, dtmOpened, dtmClicked, blnTrackOpens, blnTrackClicks, blnTrackReplies, lngMergeID, blnHide, lngLatestEventID, strClickResponse, dtmClickResponse)
    Select * From @Sample 

    Insert Into tbl1Recipients(strEmailSendID, strEmailAddress, strDisplayName, strRecipientType)
    Select * From @Rec

End
```

Comment: I just dropped the procedure from SSMS and then re-created with this. Thanks Mansi!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the stored procedure is inserting into `tbl1Recipients` before inserting into `tbl1SentEmails`. SQL Server [does not support deferred foreign-key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998095/deferrable-constraints-in-sql-server) so you need to add the row to the parent table before you add it in the table which references it.

Try switching the `INSERT` statements in your stored procedure.